# Usages de « corrigendum » et d'« erratum », quelle nuance?

Tags: usage, latin

J'aimerais être éclairé sur l'usage de ces expressions latines qui sont fort usitées.

Sont-elles synonymes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*corrigendum* est un mot utilisé par les anglophones.

Il est inconnu dans Wikipédia francophone, bien qu'il puisse être compris, les francophones utilisent *erratum*.

Pour les définitions [anglaise](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/corrigendum) et [française](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/erratum) il s'agit principalement de signaler une erreur dans un écrit.

Comment: Autrement elles recouvrent la même signification?

Comment: @menjaraz j'ai complété ma réponse